# 3.2.0-29.46-generic-pae kernel boot problem

Tags: 12.04, kernel

After updating my kernel to 3.2.0-27 I had problems getting into the system. It was working with the 3.2.0-26 though. I deleted the new kernel and everything was working fine until I started to have the same problem with the 3.2.0-26 too, after a minor update.

Every time I was getting a black screen and when I was force shutting down the PC the error message `Broken pipe` could be read for a fraction of a second. Then I thought maybe the new kernel was fixed and searched for an update and I saw the 3.2.0-29, which has the same problem.

I read some other posts with similar problems and, it's not from any nVidia driver nor ATI, I have the default VGA driver. The only option on booting up the system now (with any other kernel) is entering "Recovery mode" and then simply "resume" to normal boot which is unpleasant since I have to stay at the PC until the system boots up.

## Edit/Add

Still not working after running boot-repair. This is what I got in the terminal:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/glade2script", line 2339, in set_widget
    exec( arg )
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
gi._glib.GError: Failed to open file 'boot-repair.png': No such file or directory
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 68, in apport_excepthook
    binary = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwdu(), sys.argv[0]))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/glade2script", line 2339, in set_widget
    exec( arg )
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
gi._glib.GError: Failed to open file 'boot-repair.png': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/glade2script", line 2339, in set_widget
    exec( arg )
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
gi._glib.GError: Failed to open file 'boot-repair.png': No such file or directory
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 68, in apport_excepthook
    binary = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwdu(), sys.argv[0]))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/glade2script", line 2339, in set_widget
    exec( arg )
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
gi._glib.GError: Failed to open file 'boot-repair.png': No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Open up ubuntu from rescue mode.Open up the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

-Press Enter - Then type:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then open boot repair. Perform recommended repairs. If that does not fix it then paste the link here for the boot summary.

Comment: This is what i get when i run the program:
"The sda8 (The OS now in use - Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS) partition is nearly full. This can prevent to start it. Please use the file browser that just opened to delete unused files (or transfer them to another disk). Close this window when you have finished." 

I only have 25GB at disposal so....

Comment: Well,I guess you got your answer. Its becuse the partition is nearly full. First remove all the unwanted software.The ones you rarely or never use. And then perform 

 sudo apt-get clean 
 sudo apt-get autoclean 
 sudo apt-get autoremove